# oracle sql use above cell calculated value in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am Trying to Apply Running Formula on A Column like this.I tried much i am still unable to do this.Plz any one give idea to do this using oracle sql,

```
EMP NO  SAL DEDUCTION BALANCE
1       10  5          10-5=5
1       10  2          5-2=3
1       15  2          3-2=1
1       21  1          1-1=0
```

I used the lag function but it returned the same value of above cell.

Comment: start by phrasing your question in proper English so people may actually understand what you are asking. As it it's utterly incomprehensible.

Comment: plz any one give answer

Comment: need a bit more info here: Looks like you're starting with sal and subtracting DEDUCTION every row.  But you're ignoring EMP NO and SAL on consecutive rows?

Comment: yes i just want this that next deduction should be done from prev balance for all employees

Comment: consider this with a single employee with different salaries and deduction.hope this is now clear to you

Comment: It's not clear to me. Which column do you need to calculate, `deduction` or `balance` ? Why the first balance is `10-5=5` but not  for example `21-1=20` (from the last record) or `15-2=13` (from the third row) ?

Comment: the second record balance should `10-2` or you want the result of first record to be used for the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a sorting field to get the difference correctly.

I introduced an incremented field to simulate some sorting.
I supposed that different employees have not different deductions. Otherwise you can partition by EMP_NO.

If I correctly understood your need, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(SORT_KEY   NUMBER,
 EMP_NO     NUMBER,
 SAL        NUMBER,
 DEDUCTION  NUMBER);

INSERT INTO T VALUES(1, 1, 10, 5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES(2, 1, 10, 2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES(3, 1, 15, 2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES(4, 1, 21, 1);

COMMIT;

SELECT SORT_KEY, SAL,
       ABS(V) AS DEDUCTION,
       SUM(V) OVER(ORDER BY SORT_KEY) AS BALANCE
FROM (SELECT SORT_KEY, SAL,
             CASE WHEN LAG(DEDUCTION, 1) OVER(ORDER BY SORT_KEY) IS NULL
                  THEN SAL - DEDUCTION
                  ELSE - DEDUCTION END AS V
      FROM t
      ORDER BY SORT_KEY)
ORDER BY SORT_KEY;

SORT_KEY   SAL   DEDUCTION  BALANCE
--------   --    ---------  -------
       1   10    5          5
       2   10    2          3
       3   15    2          1
       4   21    1          0

DROP TABLE T PURGE;
```

Partitioning by EMP_NO (if this is what you want):

```
INSERT INTO T VALUES(5, 2, 10, 5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES(6, 2, 10, 2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES(7, 2, 15, 2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES(8, 2, 21, 1);

COMMIT;

SELECT SORT_KEY, EMP_NO, SAL,
       ABS(V) AS DEDUCTION,
       SUM(V) OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_NO ORDER BY SORT_KEY) AS BALANCE
FROM (SELECT SORT_KEY, EMP_NO, SAL,
             CASE WHEN LAG(DEDUCTION, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_NO ORDER BY SORT_KEY) IS NULL
                  THEN SAL - DEDUCTION
                  ELSE - DEDUCTION END AS V
      FROM t
      ORDER BY SORT_KEY)
ORDER BY EMP_NO, SORT_KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the business requirements are still a mystery to me, here's one way to do it (I've added a rn column to introduce an ordering on the rows):

```
with employees as (
  select 1 as rn, 1 as emp_no,10 as sal,5 as deduction, '10-5=5' as balance from dual union all 
  select 2 as rn, 1 as emp_no,10 as sal,2 as deduction, '5-2=3' as balance from dual union all 
  select 3 as rn, 1 as emp_no,15 as sal,2 as deduction, '3-2=1' as balance from dual union all 
  select 4 as rn, 1 as emp_no,21 as sal,1 as deduction, '1-1=0' as balance from dual )
select v1.*, 
  v1.sal - v1.aggr_deduction as remaining_sal_current_sal,
  v1.first_sal - v1.aggr_deduction as remaining_sal_first_sal 
from (
select rn,
       emp_no, 
       sal, 
       deduction,
       balance,
       sum(deduction) over (partition by emp_no order by rn) as aggr_deduction,
       (select sal from employees e1 where rn = 1 ) as first_sal
from employees
) v1
order by rn
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19bfe/1)